# How to load the contents of a local text file by name using Javascript and HTML 5?

Tags: javascript, html, file, filereader, fileapi

Working in Chrome, loading a ***local*** html or JS file.

I found many examples of how to load a file that is selected using the Choose File input.

However, didn't figure out how to do it ***given a file name*** without using the Choose File input.

The Choose File input returns a File object.

How to create the File object without the Choose File input?

From the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File):

```
new File(
  Array parts,
  String filename, 
  BlobPropertyBag properties
);
```

But didn't figure out what the parts and properties would be.

Edit: Use case:

I have code coverage results generated as part of a test suite. It is stored as JSON (which is easy to read), but I need to display it with the source code.

So the feature is to load the source code and JSON data, and render them together on a web page using HTML and Javascript.

The file would be opened from the browser and lives on the local machine. There is no server.

Comment: Maybe you need the XMLHttpRequest? It is a tool for loading any files over HTTP protocol.

Comment: As I stated in the question, this is not for an HTTP request. This is for reading a local file without a server.

Comment: Websites can not access the hard drive of a visitor without a permission. If they could, any website would be able to read any private files, install viruses or simply clear the hard drive.

Comment: It's not for a website.

Comment: @BSeven What is it then? If it's a browser extension, then the answers are very different.

Comment: Maybe you can describe what is your intent? And really, you can't see a single byte from the visitor's hard drive without him explicitly clicking Open to allow you to read it.

Comment: There is no visitor.

Comment: If you "thing" is opened in a browser, it is a webpage. And if somebody "uses" your "thing", which is a webpage, he is a visitor.

Comment: Apparently the real problem is a secret. I guess the answer will have to be a secret then too.

Comment: Yes, I know it is a webpage. I don't think of myself as a visitor to my own machine browsing the local filesystem.

Comment: I have added the use case. Please see edit.

Comment: Can you explain why a file selector doesn't do what you need? It would even give you the ability to reuse the program for many files, at the will of the user.

Comment: Yes, because I don't want the user to have select a file. They select the file when they open it with the browser.

Comment: If the file is small, you can save it and open it using localStorage, without users permission. Otherwise, just start a local HTTP server (there is a Chrome extension for that) and use XMLHttpRequest. Once, I used JS to process a 22 GB file.

Answer (score 7):

The browser cannot load arbitrary files by name from your filesystem without special extensions or other shenanigans. This is a security policy to prevent random web sites from reading files from your hard disk as you browse the internet.

If you're down to do something special like if you want to write a chrome app, you could get access to some nice APIs for accessing the filesystem:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem

Comment: Although I have seen this before, it does not make much sense because: 1. You **can** load any local file using the Choose File input. 2. HTML files loaded from the local filesystem typically have different permissions than those served by remote hosts.

Comment: @BSeven Sure, you can load any file, but *only after the user selects it*. That's what gives it security.

Answer (score 4):

The `File` constructor doesn't read a file from the harddrive, but rater make a virtual file, consider this:

```
var file = new File(["some", "content"], "/tmp/my-name.txt");
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
  console.log(reader.result); // somecontent
};
```

No file will be read or stored on the clients machine.

If you are talking about creating files in [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) then you should take a look at `fs`.

Comment: I don't think it's node.js, because the question started with "Working in Chrome"

Comment: @4castle valid point. I just mentioned it in case OP got [tag:v8] and [tag:google-chrome] mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons all browsers don't support predefined values on file fields so the answer is you can't.