# Generate Base64 String with local url of image without input type file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, base64

I am trying to generate a base64 string of local URL of image. I searched a lot for that but didn't got any answer. I found many example to convert a base64 string with a HTTP URL of image but I have local URL of image. I tried it with create a file object but its not working. Here is a example what I tried:

```
convertFileToDataURLviaFileReader(url){
    var file = new File([""],url, {type: "image/jpeg"});
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event) => {
        var base64 = event.target.result;
        return base64;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);     
}
```

Here URL is a absolute path of image : `file:\\C:\Users\abc\Pictures\butterfly.jpg`
This example is not generating a base64 image completely ie only returning a blank string :

Output

```
data:/
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from your function.

Comment: forget to added a line. Question is edited now @Mardoxx

Comment: It is not working with local files, File don't have any constructor.Please see the documentation, there is no magic -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: it will working fine when i used it with input type file. It will take a local file and i have created a base64 with input type file. But now i want to generate manually without input type file @AlexNikulin

Comment: please refer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958078/resize-a-base-64-image-in-javascript-without-using-canvas][1]

Comment: @Gitesh Purbia You are right, you can do this only with input type file, but you can't create file from path

Comment: ok can i do this with server side ? @AlexNikulin

Comment: if you have file on server, you can create file from server path.But in client side you can't do this (security reasons)

Comment: you can look the similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37425044/5138198